# Hi i am facing problem to send whatsapp message to a particular group using intent

Tags: android, whatsapp

Hi i am facing problem to send whats app message to a particular group using intent . I can send whats app message to a particular chat contact using intent . But i am not able to send to a whats app group . I have also tried using whats app api and passing whats app group id. but it navigates to invite contact link and if contact is already in group it shows you are  already developer

Comment: describe more. what you have trying so far with code ?

Comment: I am trying to place a text to a whats app group which i am a member using intent by passing whats app group id and message. using url https://chat.whatsapp.com/uniqueId where unique id i have taken from group share option

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to the particular group you need **group shared the link** [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDbbH.jpg), use that link and try below code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://chat.whatsapp.com/uniqueId");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Comment: Thanks sniffer .But i have tried this solution also but it just navigates to the whats app group and showing only you are  already in group and not placing the text message that i have passed as extra text .